# Extract and extend bbox from image, and create a new bbox labelling where the desired object is new image

Tags: c#, json, crop, system.text.json

I have this code piece which purpose is to extract the bbox as cropped region, and corresponding coco formatted json.

I used these images to train a my model, but want to train on images with more noise in them, which I hope I can achieve but extracting images which bigger versions of labelled bbox.

My code is currently only able to extract each labelled bbox as croppedregion of the image, and for them coresponding coco formatted json.

But how should i go about extracting an extended cropped regions, and create an updated coco formattet json.

My first idea was to extend with a fix margin -  but then I ran into the issue of going out of border of the original image.

Any idea on how I can extract an extended version of my labelled bbox, and also create a coco formatted json with the updated information in regards to where the labelled bbox is supposed to be in the extended bbox.

Here is my current code capable of extracting the bbox and creating a coco formatted json based on that.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text.Json;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string inputJsonPath = @"C:\Users\k\Downloads\project-1-at-2023-12-29-05-06-4170ee05 - Copy\result.json";
        string outputJsonPath = @"C:\Users\k\Downloads\project-1-at-2023-12-29-05-06-4170ee05 - Copy\new_dataset.json";
        string outputImagesPath = @"C:\Users\k\Downloads\project-1-at-2023-12-29-05-06-4170ee05 - Copy\1xImages";
        string imageDirectoryPath = @"C:\Users\k\Downloads\project-1-at-2023-12-29-05-06-4170ee05 - Copy\";
        CreateNewDataset(inputJsonPath, outputJsonPath, outputImagesPath, imageDirectoryPath);
    }

    static void CreateNewDataset(string inputJsonPath, string outputJsonPath, string outputImagesPath, string imageDirectoryPath)
    {
        // Read the original COCO dataset JSON
        string jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(inputJsonPath);
        JsonDocument cocoData = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonContent);

        // Create a new COCO dataset object
        var newCocoData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["images"] = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>(),
            ["annotations"] = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>()
        };

        // Create output directory for new images
        Directory.CreateDirectory(outputImagesPath);

        // Process each image in the original dataset
        foreach (var imgInfo in cocoData.RootElement.GetProperty("images").EnumerateArray())
        {
            string imageFilePath = Path.Combine(imageDirectoryPath, imgInfo.GetProperty("file_name").GetString());
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(imageFilePath);

            // Process each annotation in the image
            foreach (var annId in cocoData.RootElement.GetProperty("annotations").EnumerateArray().Where(ann => ann.GetProperty("image_id").GetInt16() == imgInfo.GetProperty("id").GetInt16()))
            {
                var annInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (var property in annId.EnumerateObject())
                {
                    annInfo[property.Name] = property.Value.Clone();
                }

                var bboxArray = ((JsonElement)annInfo["bbox"]).EnumerateArray().Select(e => e.GetDouble()).ToArray();

                // Crop the region from the original image using the old bounding box
                var oldBboxInt = bboxArray.Select(coord => Convert.ToInt32(coord)).ToList();
                Bitmap croppedRegion = new Bitmap(image.Clone(new Rectangle(oldBboxInt[0], oldBboxInt[1], oldBboxInt[2], oldBboxInt[3]), image.PixelFormat));

                // Save the cropped region as a new image
                string newImageFilename = $"cropped_{(imgInfo.GetProperty("file_name").GetString()).Replace("\\", string.Empty)}";
                string newImageFilePath = Path.Combine(outputImagesPath, newImageFilename);
                croppedRegion.Save(newImageFilePath);

                // Update the annotation information for the new dataset
                annInfo["image_id"] = (newCocoData["images"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>).Count() + 1;
                annInfo["id"] = (newCocoData["annotations"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>).Count() + 1;
                annInfo["bbox"] = new List<object> { 0, 0, oldBboxInt[2] -  oldBboxInt[0], oldBboxInt[3] - oldBboxInt[1] };

                // Add the new image and annotation information to the new dataset
                (newCocoData["images"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>).Add(new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["id"] = annInfo["image_id"],
                    ["file_name"] = newImageFilename,
                    ["height"] = (annInfo["bbox"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>)[3],
                    ["width"] = (annInfo["bbox"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>)[2]
                });
                (newCocoData["annotations"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>).Add(annInfo);
            }
        }

        // Save the new dataset as a JSON file
        string newCocoJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(newCocoData, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
        File.WriteAllText(outputJsonPath, newCocoJson);
    }
}
```